# Moving an instanced player with move_and_slide

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am probably overthinking this or going about it the completely wrong way. Basically I want to use move_and_slide on the instanced player (aPlayer) where I've commented, #MOVE. This script is attatched to my Tilemap on an instanced Scene Level_Test.

Code in screenshot pared down for this post because it is not relevant and nonfunctional at this time.

```
extends TileMap

onready var aPlayer = preload("res://Scenes/Player.tscn").instance()

var cSpawn1 = Vector2.ZERO

func _ready() -> void:
    aPlayer.position = cSpawn1
    add_child(aPlayer)

func _physics_process(delta) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_released("iPlayerInteract"):
        _Interact()
    else:
        var vInputDirection = Vector2(Input.get_action_strength("iPlayerRight") - Input.get_action_strength("iPlayerLeft"), Input.get_action_strength("iPlayerDown") - Input.get_action_strength("iPlayerUp"))
        if vInputDirection != Vector2.ZERO:
            _Move(aPlayer, vInputDirection)

func _Interact():
    pass

func _Move(vSelf, vDirection):
    #MOVE
    pass
```

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Player Scene]

Comment: Please describe the issue you encountered with this approach. I presume you called `vSelf.move_and_slide(...)` on `_Move`, right? Did it do something unexpected? Did you get an error? - Edit: I presume it could be an error if (the root node of) `Player.tscn` is not a kinematic body. And for something unexpected, perhaps you have some other code on that scene that causes a conflict.

Comment: Added image of Player scene. vSelf.move_and_slide(etc) reports "nonexistent function ...in base Node2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The player.tscn scene as depicted in the screenshot is structured as follows:

```
Player (Node2d)
└ Body (KinematicBody2D)
  ├ Camera (Camera2D)
  ├ Collision (CollisionShape2D)
  └ Sprite (Sprite)
```

This is what gets instanced here:

```
onready var aPlayer = preload("res://Scenes/Player.tscn").instance()
```

That sets `aPlayer` to the root node of the instanced scene, which is a [`Node2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html).

And thus what you pass into `_Move` (`_Move(aPlayer, vInputDirection)`) is a `Node2D`, which do not have `move_and_slide`, and thus calling `move_and_slide` on it results in error.

Instead `move_and_slide` exists in [`KinematicBody`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody.html)(3D) and [`KinematicBody2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html).

The simple and elegant solution is make the `KinematicBoyd2D` (`Body`) the root of the scene. *There is a "Make Scene Root" in the contextual menu you get on secondary click on the Scene panel, which will do that.*

Alternatively you could also reach into the scene with `get_node`, for example:

```
vSelf.get_node("Body").move_and_slide(...)
```

Or for example:

```
onready var aPlayer = preload("res://Scenes/Player.tscn").instance().get_node("Body")
```

**Addendum**: There is another way if you think about it. You can add a script to the root node (`Player`) and declare whatever functions you want there, including but not limited to a `move_and_slide` that delegates to the `KinematicBody2D` (`Body`).

I should also point out that `move_and_slide` will move the `KinematicBody2D`, but not its parent. So the `position` property on the `Player` node will no longer be the position of the `KinematicBody2D`. And, well, you avoid all the trouble if you make the `KinematicBody2D` the root.